# InputStream does not want to read from a textfile android studio

Tags: java, android, inputstream, bufferedreader

I have problems with android programming in java, because it does not want to read from a text file. The problem is that the buttons do not add the text which I am trying to do in the async-class. Furthermore, the buttons which will show the text does not work, because when I press on a button the application stops working.

Short introduction of the program:

The application starts with a value sent to gameAction from a spinner, and from there it wil invoke a name on text-file which will be loaded into strings in an array-list, the class QuestionBox. Lastly it will questions will be made in GameAction class.

If something was unclear, please comment. And any help is appreciated! Excuse me for adding a lot of code, but I added it due to not knowing how to do.

```
public class QuestionBox extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Object>{

private Context context;
private Callback callback;
private List<Question> mQuestions;
public QuestionBox(Context context,Callback callback)
{
    mQuestions = new ArrayList<Question>();
    this.callback=callback;
    this.context= context;

}
public  Callback getCallback(){

    return callback;
}


@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {

InputStream iS = null;
    try {
        iS = context.getAssets().open("hogskoleprovet.txt");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //System.out.println("Hit kom du");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iS));




    String question, answer, answerOne, answerTwo, answerThree, answerFour;



    try {
        while (reader.readLine() != null) {

            //reading some lines from resource file
            question = reader.readLine();
            answer = reader.readLine();
            answerOne = reader.readLine();
            answerTwo = reader.readLine();
            answerThree = reader.readLine();

            answerFour = reader.readLine();
            Question q = new Question(question, answer, answerOne, answerTwo, answerThree, answerFour);
            mQuestions.add(q);

            break;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        reader.close();
        System.out.println("Hit kom du3");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}

public interface Callback{
    public void notify_result(List<Question> question_list);





    }





@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);


}






public int getQuestionsLeft() {
    return mQuestions.size();
}

public Question getRandomQuestion() {

    Random random = new Random();
    int index = random.nextInt(mQuestions.size());
    Question newQuestion = mQuestions.get(index);
    mQuestions.remove(index);
    return newQuestion;
}
```

}

Here is another method which the strings will be sent to:

public class gameAction extends ActionBarActivity implements QuestionBox.Callback{

```
private QuestionBox mQuestionBox;
private Question mCurrentQuestion;
private Context context;
private Callback callback;

@Override
public void notify_result(List<Question> question_list) {

}



 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_action);
    //Kod som kollar vad som skickades med när aktiviteten startades
    Intent callingIntent = getIntent();
    int index = callingIntent.getIntExtra("INDEX",0);

    //Bestäm filnamn beroende på vad som skickades med


    if(index==0){


        mQuestionBox =new QuestionBox(getApplicationContext(), this);
        mQuestionBox.execute("hogskoleprovet.txt");

    }
    else {
        if (index == 1 ) {
            mQuestionBox =new QuestionBox(getApplicationContext(), this);
            mQuestionBox.execute("hogskoleprovet.txt");



        } else if (index == 1) {
            mQuestionBox =new QuestionBox(getApplicationContext(), this);
            mQuestionBox.execute("hogskoleprovet.txt");



        } else if (index == 2) {
            mQuestionBox =new QuestionBox(getApplicationContext(), this);
            mQuestionBox.execute("hogskoleprovet.txt");



        }
    }







}


public void setNewQuestion()
{

    //Hämta en slumpmässig fråga från vår QuestionBox
    //och lagra den i mCurrentQuestion
    mCurrentQuestion = mQuestionBox.getRandomQuestion();


    //Se till så att textfält och knappar visar den aktuella
    //frågan

    TextView questionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.questionTextView);
    questionTextView.setText(mCurrentQuestion.getQuestion());


    Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOne);
    buttonOne.setText(mCurrentQuestion.getOptionOne());


    Button buttonTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTwo);
    buttonTwo.setText(mCurrentQuestion.getOptionTwo());


    Button buttonThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonThree);
    buttonThree.setText(mCurrentQuestion.getOptionThree());

    Button buttonFour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFour);
    buttonFour.setText(mCurrentQuestion.getOptionFour());

    Button buttonNew = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNew);

    buttonOne.setEnabled(true);
    buttonTwo.setEnabled(true);
    buttonThree.setEnabled(true);
    buttonFour.setEnabled(true);


    buttonNew.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    buttonOne.setText(mCurrentQuestion.getOptionOne());
    buttonTwo.setText(mCurrentQuestion.getOptionTwo());
    buttonThree.setText(mCurrentQuestion.getOptionThree());
    buttonFour.setText(mCurrentQuestion.getOptionFour());


}
public void quitTheGame(View v){

    Intent intent = new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);
    Button butttonQuit =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFive);
    startActivity(intent);

}




public void answerClick(View V)
{
    Button answerButton = (Button)V;
    Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOne);
    buttonOne.setText(mCurrentQuestion.getOptionOne());


    Button buttonTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTwo);
    buttonTwo.setText(mCurrentQuestion.getOptionTwo());


    Button buttonThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonThree);
    buttonThree.setText(mCurrentQuestion.getOptionThree());

    Button buttonFour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFour);
    buttonFour.setText(mCurrentQuestion.getOptionFour());

    Button buttonNew = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNew);



    buttonOne.setEnabled(false);
    buttonTwo.setEnabled(false);
    buttonThree.setEnabled(false);
    buttonFour.setEnabled(false);


    buttonNew.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



}


public void newClick(View v){

    if(mQuestionBox.getQuestionsLeft()>0){
        setNewQuestion();

    }


    else
    {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        String text = "Slut på frågor!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();

    }

}






@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Here is the class for putting answer to correct options:

package com.example.arnpet.ultimatehogskoleprovet;

```
public class Question {

private String question;//Lagrar frågan

private String optionOne; //Lagrar svarsalternativ

private String optionTwo;

private String optionThree;

private String optionFour;

private String correctAnswer; //Lagrar det korrekta svaret
```

//konstruktor

```
public Question (String question, String optionOne, String optionTwo,
                 String optionThree, String optionFour, String correctAnswer)
{
    this.question = question;
    this.optionOne = optionOne;
    this.optionTwo = optionTwo;
    this.optionThree = optionThree;
    this.optionFour = optionFour;





}

public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public String getOptionOne() {
    return optionOne;
}

public String getOptionTwo() {
    return optionTwo;
}

public String getOptionThree() {
    return optionThree;
}

public String getOptionFour() {
    return optionFour;
}
```

}

Comment: Your wall of code helps nobody - please search for 'how to ask a good question' and try again.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (reader.readLine() != null)
```

Here you are reading a line of the file and throwing it away. Not what you want, unless your file is strangely structured with ignorable junk lines every so often.

The usual loop looks like this:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
```

and then using `line` in the controlled block.

Secondly, this is the only place you check for null, yet you have several other `readLine()` calls, any one of which can return null. So you run some risk of NPEs later in your code.

Comment: What do you mean by controlled block? How should I avoid NPES?

Comment: Shouldn't I initiate line or create it as variable because my android studio says it's not resolved to a symbol?

Comment: The 'controlled block' is the block that `while` controls. You avoid NPEs by testing for null, obviously. You need to declare `line` before you use it, just like any other variable, obviously.

Comment: Sorry, I do not really get this, should I put for example  question = line; Or other way

Comment: Please, can you do this part for me because I do not understand what you mean by " Secondly, this is the only place you check for null, yet you have several other readLine() calls, any one of which can return null. So you run some risk of NPEs later in your code" ?